# Installing Packages in Python - Pip/cmd vs Putting File in Lib/site-packages

Tags: python, package

Whenever I google 'importing X package/module' I always see a bunch of tutorials about using pip or the shell commands. But I've always just taken the downloaded file and put it in the site-packages folder, and when I just use 'import' in PyCharm it has worked just fine.

The reason I was wondering was because I was downloading NumPy today, and when I just copied the file the same way I'd been doing, PyCharm didn't show any errors. I was just wondering if I'm misunderstanding this whole concept of installing packages.

EDIT: Thank you for your answers! I am off to learn how to use pip now.

Answer (score 2):

Package manager solves things like dependencies and uninstalling.

Additionally, when using `pip` to install packages, packages are usually being built with `setup.py` script. While it might not be an issue for pure Python modules, if package contains any extension modules or some other custom stuff, copying files to `site-packages` just won't work (I'm actually not sure why it worked in your case with `numpy`, since it does contain C extensions modules).

Answer (score 2):

One of the points of using a package manager (pip) is *portability*. With pip, you just include a requirements.txt in your project and you can work on it on any machine, be it Windows, Linux, or Mac. When moving to a new environment/OS, pip will take care of installing the packages properly for you; note that packages can have OS-specific steps so your copy-pasted Windows set-up might now work when you move to another OS.

Moreover, with your copy-paste method, you carry the bulk of your dependencies everywhere. I imagine that if you want to switch machines (not necessarily OS), you copy **everything** from project code to dependencies. With pip, you can keep your working directories leaner, all at the cost of a single requirements.txt.